Get Typeof Table which is passed as variable
var TemplateGroupList = _templateGTRRepository
    .GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.TemplateGroupId == template.Id)
    .ToList();

var PropertyList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in TemplateGroupList)
{
    var tableType = Type.GetType(item.TableName);

    if (tableType != null)
    { 
        var properties = (from t in tableType.GetProperties()
                          select t.Name).ToList();
        foreach (var propertyName in properties)
        {
            PropertyList.Add($"{item.TableName}.{propertyName}");
        }
    }
}

Error: always getting null tableType.

It's really not clear what you are doing here. What is _templateGTRRepository and what does GetAll return? Did you just mean to use item.GetType() here to get the class used for your entity?

IM GETTIGN A LIST OF TABLE NAME FROM DATABASE USING REPOSITORY AND THEN TRYING TO GETTING THE PROPERTY OF THAT ENTITY
BY CONVERTING THAT TABLE NAME TO ENTITY TYPE

You're doing Type.GetType(item.TableName) which searches for a type with the name of the value of item.TableName (assuming TableName is a string), judging by your comment you probably want to do var tableType = item.GetType(); to get the type C# that represents your table. P.S please don't yell

Please [edit] the question to add new information. As usual, the repository pattern doesn't help to make code clear. We only see black-box code here. No idea what all these object look like or where they come from.

To get the Type of some class by string class name, you need to submit the assembly as well to GetType method. One solution to the problem is to load the assembly by name and then load the type by name from the assembly
var assembly = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");

// assume that item.TableName is namespase plus class name
// example: "TestApp.Data.TableName"
var type = assembly.GetType(item.TableName);

